# Joda Time library in scala returning incorrect date

Tags: java, scala, jodatime

Im using the joda time library in my scala code. My code is as follows .

```
val dt:DateTime = new DateTime()
val dtf:DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd")
return dtf.print(dt.minusDays(1))
```

Assuming the current date is March 11 2011,the above code should return the string 2011-03-10,but the output i get is `2011-52-10`

What could be causing this problem ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) the pattern `mm` is for minutes, use `MM` for months.